# REST, Tomcat, Jersey, IntelliJ, produces 404

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey

This has been driving me nuts. I have tried everything in about five Stack Overflow questions about the same error, to no avail.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Spotitube</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.spotitube</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My service:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/myresource")
public class myresource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml, should it be relevant somehow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spotitube</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotitube3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And the index.jsp just contains a link to my service at localhost:8080/rest/myresource. URL checks out.

I have tried Tomcat 7 and 8.5. My IDE is IntelliJ 2017.2.5. I've added all the jar files as the tutorial I followed ordered me to, and Tomcat works fine. Only at the RESTful page (not at the index.jsp) does it give a 404.

I feel stupid now. Anyone got any clue what could be going on?

Comment: Have you conform port number ???
And What was the result of jsp???

Comment: Port number is 8080. The jsp shows up fine. Clicking the link in the jsp (leading the the REST service, url verified) gives a 404 page.

Comment: I think Your code is of maven archtype for rest and it is directly deployed in tomcat so it should work fine with out any error so it can be problem of your server.

Comment: It is actually of a Java EE archetype I got from the IDE, with Maven support added later.
I have already tried two different Tomcat versions...

Comment: It is batter to use direct maven archtype then added support it may have problem with location of things like where web.xml and the location of myresource.java file

Comment: Ok, which Maven archetype would you suggest I use then? There's a whole list, and none of them look obvious to me.

Comment: you can use any of these https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes

Answer (score 1):

Because the mapping URL is  `localhost:8080/myresource` not  `localhost:8080/rest/myresource`

Comment: Mapping URL? You mean, the `@Path("/myresource")` line? I thought that rest was added in front of it by default?

Comment: In any case, changing it to either `@Path("rest/myresource")` or `@Path("/rest/myresource")` does nothing.

Comment: Could you please share the link you are requesting to?

Comment: Did you restart and redeply? `@Path("/rest/myresource")` should work given that your servlet mapping url-pattern is `"/rest/*"` and the application context is `"/"`

Comment: I obviously did. Nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

first of all, check that Application Context is "/".

[image]

Secondly, as Mehraj Malik said above, check that Mapping URL is correct or not.

Comment: Application Context is indeed "/".

Comment: What is Mapping URL in this context? Is it the line `@Path("/myresource")` in the service class, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mehraj wrote (use `@Path("/rest/myresource")`), it seems you might have forgotten to define your jersey application in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.company.project.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.spotitube</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In any case if you could post the relevant code in your jersey application that might help.

It should begin like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
```